# Evento posterior a OnBindViewHolder - RecyclerView

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, recyclerview

Estoy intentando en `Xamarin.Android` que las imagenes dentro de mi `CardView` queden del mismo ancho que el CardView (todo el ancho de la pantalla) y que tomen el alto que necesiten para que la imagen mantenga su relacion ancho-alto.

Lo intente desde el diseño `XML` setando el `width = match_parent` y el `height = wrap_content`, pero no funciona correctamente siempre; la imagen la sube el cliente y puede ser de cualquier tamaño por lo que un tamaño fijo o un `scaleType = fitXY` no funciona.

Es por eso que intente lograr el comportamiento deseado con este codigo en el evento `OnBindViewHolder`:

```
float oAncho = hh.card.Width; 
float iAncho = hh.imgAsync.Width; float iAlto = hh.imgAsync.Height;

float Diferencia = oAncho - iAncho;
int p = Convert.ToInt32(iAncho + Diferencia);
int q = Convert.ToInt32(iAlto + Diferencia);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms =
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(p, q);
hh.imgFeed.LayoutParameters = parms;
```

El problema es que la primera vez que carga el CardView al no haber terminado de inflar (inflate) el CardView los tamaños de los controles son igual a 0 (cero). Hasta que scrolleo hacia abajo y luego nuevamente hacia arriba a los elementos ya mostrados anteriormente es que logro el comportamiento deseado.

Si hubiera algun evento posterior al OnBindViewHolder creo que seria optimo hacer el formateo ahi pero por lo que he leido no existe tal evento.

Alguna idea practica de como lograr el comportamiento deseado?

**Comportamiento no deseado (a corregir)**

(En la foto el CardView es menos ancho que la pantalla pero es solo para un ejemplo).
[image: error]

**Comportamiento deseado**

(imagen = ancho de la pantalla)

[image: bien]

Answer (score 0):

Una solución a tu problema podría ser esto. En el XML, el cardView debe contar con la siguiente etiqueta:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Además, si quieres que la CardView ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla, asegúrate que no contenga márgenes la vista.

Dentro de la cardView agrega una imagen que esté dentro de un LinnearLayout, tal que así:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Media -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="194dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/media"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_media"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Aquí lo importante es la etiqueta `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`del ImageView. Esta indicación hará que todas las imágenes se tengan que ajustar de acuerdo a las dimensiones de su contenedor. Te recomiendo que utilices una altura de tus imágenes establecida, como yo que ocupé 194dp.

Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la documentación de Material Design para la implementación de las CardViews. Aquí te dejo el link: https://material.io/components/cards/android#card

Comment: Gracias Rocko, lo intente pero no me resulta. Adjunto link de como se ve la imagen en el cardview: https://ibb.co/7grVg2P  -- y la imagen deberia de verse asi: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51fWOBx3agL._AC_.jpg

Comment: Oh vale. En ese sentido, entonces habría que cambiar el android:layout_height de la imagen y poner wrap_content, para que la CardView se estire de acuerdo a la altura de las imágenes. También es importante que tu CardView tenga como android:layout_height en wrap_content... Mmm... creo que eso lo solucionaría... Igual, intenta en ajustar la etiqueta "android:scaleType" en el ImageView de acuerdo a lo que buscas. Quizá no sea necesario su uso y puedas eliminar esta etiqueta. Un consejo, si presionas Ctrl+BarraEspaciadora en el valor de la etiqueta de "android:scaleType", te saldrán sus opciones.